# Can terminal close itself after stop debug in VSCode?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, terminal, visual-studio-code

I recently use VSCode to debug node.js program on Linux, is it a way to configure the terminal to close itself after I stop debug

Comment: Great question this just started as of v0.5.0 I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you are looking for:

```json
"debug.console.closeOnEnd": true
```